# Ubuntu 16.04 iPhone iOs 10 Bluetooth Devices not allowing Browse function

Tags: networking, 16.04, bluetooth, iphone, transfer

iPhone is connected and sound works. It works with the USB cable connected.

I want to browse and move files/pictures from my iPhone 5 to my Ubuntu 16.04 Laptop via Bluetooth instead.
Is there a fix or a workaround for this? 
I have been unable to fix it with all the searching I have been doing for the last four hours, please help.

In BlueMan I get an error

> Failed to launch default file browser
>   The specified location is not supported
>   You can enter an alternate browser in service settings.

Under Local Services -> Advanced, 'Command to start an obex ftp browser' is blank. Yes 'Receive files in Downloads folder over Bluetooth' is ticked.

The app Personal File Sharing Preferences -> Share Files over the Network comes up with an error saying

> This feature cannot be enabled because the required packages are not installed on your system.

Receive Files over Bluetooth is enabled.
When the USB cable is connected i can move pictures between the PC and phone... but browsing is still greyed out.

Comment: In dash, search **Personal File Sharing** and Enable **Received file over bluetooth**. Just want to make sure if this setting already enabled.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387  It doesn't appear that the iPhone iOS allows OBEX which is needed to browse over bluetooth